# C++ Member Reference base type 'Vertex *const' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator, constants

I am running into trouble trying to access the methods of an object stored in a vector. I know that getEdges returns an unordered map of edge but I am missing something with how to reference a Vertex object from within a vector. Help?

**In void UndirectedGraph::minSpanningTree():**

```
std::vector<Vertex*> visited;

if(vertices.begin() != vertices.end())
{
    visited.push_back(vertices.begin()->second);
    visited[0]->distance = 0;
}
else
{
    return;
}

std::vector<Vertex*>::const_iterator vit;
vit = visited.begin();
std::unordered_map<std::string, Edge> edges;
edges = vit -> getEdges();
```

**In const std::unordered_map & Vertex::getEdges() const:**

```
return edges;
```

**The error:**

```
 UndirectedGraph.cpp:112:21: error: member reference base type 'Vertex
 *const' is
       not a structure or union
         edges = vit -> getEdges();
                 ~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
```

**--EDIT--**

Changing

```
edges = vit -> getEdges();
```

to

```
edges = *(vit)->getEdges();
```

gave me the same error.

Comment: Paste the getEdges definition...

Comment: It is: return edges;

Comment: Edges was declared as: std::unordered_map<std::string, Edge> edges;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vit` is an iterator. Iteratirs work like pointers to container elements. Your container element type is `Vertex*`. Therefore `vit` works like `Vertex**`.

To call a member function given a `Vertex** p` you would have to get to a `Vertex*` first. This can be done by dereferencing `p` like this:

```
(*p)
```

and at this point you can call your member function like

```
(*p)->getEdges()
```

Iterators are no different.

Note

```
*(p)->getEdges()
```

is totally different from the above (and wrong). It is the same as

```
*((p)->getEdges())
```

and

```
(p)->getEdges()
```

is the same as

```
p->getEdges()
```

which is known not to work.

On a related note, if you are using raw pointers you are probably doing it wrong. You should either store `Vertex` objects directly in an `std::vector<Vertex>` or use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` in lieu of raw pointers.

Comment: Only I don't understand why he needs to use pointer? Why not `std::vector<Vertex>`